# django and backbone.js authentication

Tags: django, backbone.js, django-authentication

I don't understand how you handle authentication when using django and backbone.js.

Lets say I have an app where users can sign up / sign in.  Normally in django I'd just use the `@login_required` decorator with my views to test if a users is authenticated or not.  Since backbone is RESTful and uses something like json to communicate with the server, it's my understanding it doesn't have a concept of being logged in.

So how do I create an django backbone app that uses django's auth system so I can still take advantage of permissions, groups and session based auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier to keep your login and logout code in django normally, and only go to a Backbone-based template once the user is logged in. Many sites work this way.

You will also want to watch for 401 errors coming back from the server when you sync, since this can mean that the user's session has expired. (I assume django sends these.)